# Executing stored procedure via linked server through trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have created a linked server on a SQL Server connecting to an Azure SQL datawarehouse.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkedserverTest', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'AZserver.database.windows.net', @catalog=N'AEDW'

  /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LinkedserverTest', @useself=N'False', @locallogin=NULL, @rmtuser=N'SQLACcount', @rmtpassword='########'
GO        
   
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
    
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

When I execute a stored procedure of SQL DW via SSMS as below, it is getting executed as expected.

```
EXEC Linkedservername,Databasename.dbo.spname
```

But when I try to have that stored procedure executed as a part of trigger definition

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TriggerTest]
ON [dbo].[TriggerTest]
AFTER INSERT  
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC LSName.databasenm.dbo.SPname
END
```

And when I try to insert a record into the table, I get the below error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 18
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 46710, Level 20, State 1, Line 19
> Unsupported transaction manager request 0 encountered. SQL Server Parallel DataWarehousing TDS endpoint only supports local transaction request for 'begin/commit/rollback'.

So am I missing anything or it is not possible to trigger cross database stored procedures via trigger definitions

**Update :**The above issue was resolved based on suggestion provided by David.

Now I am in another issue :(

I will give you a context of what I am trying to accomplish :

I have a database server hosted in IaaS which also includes an MDS(Master data services) database along with normal one.

My intention is, whenever someone publishes a new data in an MDS table, an SP should be triggered in Azure SQL datawarehouse.

So I went with the below approach:

1. Create a linked server between IaaS SQL and Azure SQL DW
2. Create a trigger

I initially created a dummy trigger in a normal database in that server and tested out the linked server property change which you suggested and that worked as expected when I tried to insert a record into a table.

But when I followed the same process of creating a trigger on an MDS backend table, and when I am trying to insert a new records via UI explorer ; I am getting the error:
[image]

And unable to add any records.

Note: I am able to update existing records in UI but not add new records as I have created the trigger on Just Insert and not Update.

So is there any other property that I need to change ?

Note : The Is_trustworthy_On property is enabled on the MDS database already

Comment: Can you try execute at command? EXEC databasenm.dbo.SPname at [LSName];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't enlist the remote proc execution in your trigger's transaction.  So try

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkedserverTest', 
                                @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
                                @optvalue=N'false'
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question a little. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: It’s unsupported to add triggers to MDS tables.  Use the MDS Change Tracking feature instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/change-tracking-master-data-services?view=sql-server-ver15